# How to use generic interface in an Factory

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics

I have a factory which has some concrete sub classes for generating reports (.txt, .csv,.xls)
I want to make the interface of the concrete classes to be generic so that i can pass in diff types of parameters (Instead of DataTable i need to use DataSet or some other class instance as argument). Here is my interface.

```
interface IReportCreator
{
    bool Create(DataTable dt);
}
```

I made the interface as generic..like the one below

```
interface IReportCreator<T>
{
    bool Create(T args);
}
```

Now my question is how can i return the generic interface from the Factory
My previous factory code

```
class Factory
{
    static IReportCreator  GetReportCreator(string type)
    {
        IReportCreator reportCreator = null;
        if(type == "txt")
            reportCreator = new TextCreator(); 

        if(type == "csv")
            reportCreator = new CSVCreator();
    } 
}
```

And in the cient.. i call like this
IReportCreator repCreator = Factory.GetReportCreator("txt");
repCreator.Create(// the arg); // Here the argument i need to make it as generic
    class Factory
    {
        // i dont know how to return the interface here..
    }

Any help will be appreciated greatly..

Comment: Could you provide code of your Factory before?

Comment: `public IReportCreator ReportCreator{get;set;}` ?

Comment: I have placed the code of my previous factory

Answer (score 3):

```
interface IReportCreator<T>
{
  bool Create(T t);
}

class Factory
{
   public IReportCreator<T> Create<T>();
}

var factory = new Factory();
var reportCreator = factory.Create<DataTable>();
```